Unable to launch chrome browser
My chrome version is: Version 123.0.6312.86
Downloaded chrome driver: https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/124.0.6367.91/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip
After run the code getting error as:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain: chromedriver, error chromedriver must exist: C:\Users\india\Downloads\chromedriver-win32.exe
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/
Build info: version: '4.20.0', revision: '866c76ca80'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getBinaryPaths(DriverFinder.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getDriverPath(DriverFinder.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at SeleniumSessions.WebdriverBasics.main(WebdriverBasics.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: chromedriver must exist: C:\Users\india\Downloads\chromedriver-win32.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$FileStateChecker.isFile(Require.java:346)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$FileStateChecker.isExecutable(Require.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getBinaryPaths(DriverFinder.java:118)
    ... 6 more

How can I resolve this? I am trying to launch Chrome and navigate to google.com using Selenium.

We can't really help you if you don't show us your code. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted.

try to do that
1- open chrome>setting>About chrome>update chrome it will be 14.*
2- get the same version (chrome driver) from here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
3- create a new folder in the project itself with the name drivers and in this folder add the chrome.exe >> the version of chrome.exe should match your Chrome browser
public class Example {
public String user = System.getProperty("user.dir");
WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void SetUpMyBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chromedriver",user+"/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

